# Python: Trying to put the contents of a folder into a text file:

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I'm in the process of writing a python script that takes two arguments that will allow me to output the contents of a folder to a text file for me to use for another process. The snippet of I have is below:

```html
#!/usr/bin/python

import cv2
import numpy as np
import random
import sys
import os
import fileinput

#Variables:

img_path= str(sys.argv[1])
file_path = str(sys.argv[2]) 

print img_path
print file_path

cmd = 'find ' + img_path + '/*.png | sed -e "s/^/\"/g;s/$/\"/g" >'  + file_path + '/desc.txt'

print "command: ", cmd

#Generate desc.txt file:
os.system(cmd)
```

When I try and run that from my command line, I get the following output, and I have no idea how to fix it.

```html
sh: 1: s/$//g: not found
```

I tested the command I am using by running the following command in a fresh terminal instance, and it works out fine:

```html
images/*.png | sed -e "s/^/\"/g;s/$/\"/g" > desc.txt
```

Can anyone see why my snippet isn't working? When I run it, I get an empty file...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: os.system has issues, try using subprocess.call instead. It allows for far greater control of how to call external commands with arguments.

That being said, why spawn a shell command at all? Can't you use os.walk and keep it all in Python?

Comment: you could use `os.listdir()` with `fnmatch.filter()` or `glob.glob('images/*.png')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its not sending the full text for your regular expression through to bash because of how python processes and escapes string content, so the best quickest solution would be to just manually escape the back slashes in the string, because python thinks they currently are escape codes. so change this line:

```
cmd = 'find ' + img_path + '/*.png | sed -e "s/^/\"/g;s/$/\"/g" >'  + file_path + '/desc.txt'
```

to this:

```
cmd = 'find ' + img_path + '/*.png | sed -e "s/^/\\"/g;s/$/\\"/g" >'  + file_path + '/desc.txt'
```

and that should work for you.

although, the comment on your question has a great point, you could totally just do it from python, something like:

```
import os
import sys    

def main():
    # variables 
    img_path= str(sys.argv[1])
    file_path = str(sys.argv[2]) 

    with open(file_path,'w') as f:
        f.writelines(['{}\n'.format(line) for line in os.listdir(img_path) if line.endswith('*.png')])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I fully agree with Kyle. My recommendation is to do using only python code better than call bash commands from your code. Here it is my recommended code, it is longer and not as optimal than the aforementioned one, but IMHO it is a more easy to understand solution.

```html
#!/usr/bin/python

import glob
import sys
import os

# Taking arguments
img_path = str(sys.argv[1])
file_path = str(sys.argv[2])
# lets put the target filename in a variable (it is better than hardcoding it)
file_name = 'desc.txt'
# folder_separator is used to define how your operating system separates folders (unix / and windows \)
folder_separator = '\\' # Windows folders
# folder_separator = '/' # Unix folders

# better if you make sure that the target folder exists
if not os.path.exists(file_path):
    # if it does not exist, you create it
    os.makedirs(file_path)

# Create the target file (write mode).
outfile = open(file_path + '/' + file_name, 'w')

# loop over folder contents
for fname in glob.iglob("%s/*" % img_path):
    # for every file found you take only the name (assuming that structure is folder/file.ext)
    file_name_in_imgPath = fname.split('\\')[1]
    # we want to avoid to write 'folders' in the target file
    if os.path.isfile(file_name_in_imgPath):
        # write filename in the target file
        outfile.write(str(file_name_in_imgPath) + '\n')

outfile.close()
```

Comment: yes it is more readable, but needs over twice as many lines to accomplish the same goal. I was trying to show the quickest solution, but your way is more pythonic for sure

Comment: Thanks a lot Kyle. I was trying to offer an alternative and easy to read solution. Your solution is better by far, but for experienced people ;)

Comment: haha, well thank you also @DanielSerrano , sometimes i forget not everyone is quite as familiar with pythons more obscure features as i am,  but then again they are fairly useful now and again, even if people dont necessarily know exactly how its working, as long as it does haha.  thats why i drop off these little nuggets of knowledge here and there.